# Tracking down a routing error with node / express

Tags: node.js, express

I've set up my express site with [poet](http://jsantell.github.com/poet) recently.  I can use post.url and all the locals which are *provided to all views*, except the url routing - for example, in my blog.jade view:

```
 ul.blog-preview$
     each post in postList$
       li$
         a(href=#{post.url}) #{post.title}$
```

The view renders fine, but the route express tries when clicking on the post.url: "http://localhost:8080/undefined/post/poet-testundefined" where the post I was trying to reach is called 'poet-test'.  So, I tried printing out post.url within the view

```
p #{post.url}
```

and to my surprise it printed out fine as post/poet-test.  So, obviously I tried browsing to localhost:8080/post/poet-test, but that didn't work either because of a reference error on post.title, which I suspect is a problem because the post is getting lost in routing somehow.

This is my site.js (or app.js as most are called) and I've included what I think must be relevant to solving this.

```
var express   = require('express')
  , app       = module.exports = express()
  , http      = require('http')
  , poet      = require('poet')(app)

poet
  .createPostRoute()
  .createPageRoute()
  .createTagRoute()
  .createCategoryRoute()
  .init(function(locals) {
    locals.postList.forEach(function ( post ) {
  console.log('loading post: ' + post.url)
})
  })

app.configure(function(){
  //...etc
  app.use(app.router);
  //...etc
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
//Dev settings
app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions:true, showStack:true }));
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
});
//Production settings
//....etc

// controllers - load them
controllers = ["pages", "blog"]
for (i in controllers) {
  controller = require('./controllers/' + controllers[i]);
  controller.setup(app)
}

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

As you can see, I check the post.url for each post it loads in poet.init(function(post) { ... }) and each of those check out with the correct /post/title url... so, I'm a little stuck here.  Perhaps logging routes somehow with app.router() or a poet specific solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the examples in the Poet repo -- You shouldn't have to escape your hrefs.. looks like the urls in Poet are fine, just some wrestling with Jade, try this:

```
a(href=post.url) post.title
```

https://github.com/jsantell/poet/blob/master/examples/views/includes/postSnippet.jade#L3